# How To Set the ProviderUserKey in ASP.Net Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

I have a members table in my application.  The members table is a 1 to 1 relationship with the users of my application.

But we can insert more members to our application in the members table than already created users for the application.

So we can have 100 users in our application.  And we can have 200 members in our members table.  Each user has a members row, but not each member is required to be a user.

So, when the member finally claims their member row and signs up to the website, I need to be able to set the UserId (ProviderUserKey) when creating the new user for the site.

So is it possible to change the providerkey when creating a new user account?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default membership provider? I don't think you can if so. It will create a unique key. You need to either create a custom provider and fix the code to include an ifUserExists method, create a user for every member and just assign them a limited role, or add a foreign key linking the two tables and let them each have non-matching IDs.